# Dúvida em um código Python de definição de números primos

Tags: python, funções

```
def primo(num):
   
    for i in range(2,21):#for i in range(1,20):
        if num==i:#num==i+1
            continue
        
        if num%i==0:#if num%i+1==0:
            return False         
        else:return True
               
        


for i in range(1, 20):
    if primo(i+1):
            print(i+1, end=" ")
print()


#Output atual (correto):2 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19
#Output antigo(errado):2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Fiz esse código Python que mostra na tela os números primos entre 1 e 20.
Eu estava tendo dificuldades para conseguir o output esperado (que está comentado na penúltima linha), essa dificuldade aconteceu pois dentro do corpo da função "primo" eu estava usando as linhas que lá estão comentadas ao invés das que estão sendo usadas agora, e com isso, o output estava sendo toda a sequência de números de 2 até 20.
Eu resolvi tal problema transformando as linhas que estão comentadas na função para o modo em que elas estão agora, no entanto, eu não entendi o motivo de os dois modelos darem resultados diferentes, sendo que nos cálculos que fiz enquanto programava, ambas as formas deveriam dar o output correto.

Comment: Lucas, seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Vale lembrar que a função [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) tem o segundo argumento "não inclusivo"; ou seja, se escrever `range(1, 10)` teremos `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` e não `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`. Se quiser que o número incluso no segundo argumento esteja presente na iteração, terá que usar `range(1, numero_que_quer + 1)`.

Comment: Obrigado. Então, tendo isso em vista, eu estava usando `contador+1` nos testes lógicos para que o valor analisado fosse sempre uma unidade maior que o contador, sendo assim, teoricamente os valores analisados seriam `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]`. No entanto, creio que não foi bem isso que aconteceu na prática, tal sequência numérica só ocorreu de fato quando, assim como você disse, eu usei `range(2, numero_que_quer + 1)`. Isso me leva a crer que o Python não aceita que eu adicione um valor ao contador dentro do teste lógico, certo? (por exemplo: `if num%cont+1==0:`)

Comment: @Lucas, ele permite sim, mas é preciso tomar cuidado com  o uso dos parênteses ou não entrará na verificação. Veja o exemplo que montei [aqui](https://www.online-python.com/KoPv9hkqVY)

Comment: Relacionado: [Perguntas frequentes que já foram respondidas no SOpt - Números primos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8697/3774)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código está certo em parte (9 não é primo), porém o que realmente criou o problema é que você desconsiderou a prioridade dos cálculos. Assim como no dia-a-dia ao calcular fazemos primeiro multiplicação e divisão e somente após isso ocorre a soma e subtração, nas linguagens de programação ocorre o mesmo.

```
'''
Digamos que o num = 10 e i = 4
if num%i+1==0:  #A prioridade dessa forma é o cálculo do % e depois disso o +
## O cálculo seria esse: 
## 10%4 = 2
## 2 +1 == 0 --> Não vai entrar no if
Porém, se fizermos
if num%(i+1)==0:    #A prioridade do cálculo vai ser + e depois o %
## Ficando assim:
## 4+1 = 5
## 10%5 == 0 --> vai entrar no if
'''
```

Fiz algumas mudanças no código para corrigir alguns erros quando verificava os números primos e para otimizar o código. Ficando assim

```
def primo(num):
    primo = True
    for i in range(2, int((num)/2)+1):
    #O for só precisa percorrer até a metade+1 do tamanho do número
    #se ainda não tiver achado nenhum divisor é porque não há
        if num%i==0:
            primo = False
            break
    return primo
               
for i in range(2, 21):
    if primo(i):
            print(i, end=" ")
print()

##Output: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19
```